# ajax and php directories

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

- I have a directory let's callit `dir1` I have an html file in it it's called `index.html` and I have in the same directory `.htaccess` file which routes all urls to `index.html` .
- I have also a dirctory in `dir1` clled `dir2` it has php file called `index.php` .
- `index.html` sends requests to `index.php` with ajax the request works correctly when the url is `localhost/dir1/` or  and also works with `localhost/dir1/index.html` or `localhost/dir1/anything_here` because of the `.htaccess` file when the url is `localhost/dir1/anything/` it doesn't work as it should or also when the url is `localhost/dir1/anything/anything/any../..` etc.

What is the solution of this problem ??

Comment: You should also post the content of the .htaccess file. We cannot know if the .htaccess file is correct or wrong if we don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use absolute URLs instead of relative ones. So, basically, the requests should be done to `/path/to/the/php/file.php` instead of `path/to/...`

Comment: do you mean I use the system directory

Comment: no, I mean you must change your ajax options to send the requests to `/dir1/dir2/index.php`

Comment: Put the htaccess content on your question to see what's wrong

Comment: I changed the dir that ajax request to from dir2/index.php to /dir1/dir2/index.php I think that what you mean ??

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\ /.*?static/(css|js|img)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ o/o/o/o/index.html [L,QSA]
`

Comment: Try adding this condition also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/dir1/dir2/index.php`

Comment: to be specific the ajax returns the same html page and prints it

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir1/dir2/index\.php$

Comment: `<?php
if(isset($_GET['anything'])){
 echo("GET =".$_GET['anything']);
} else {
 echo("no get");
}`

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the `base` tag in `head` section:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://url.com/dir1/">
</head>
```